# SSD as A Storage Drive

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, performance

I have a laptop with 2 SATA port and one PCIE for WIFI Card (though it can also be used with mini PCIE), one of the SATA port already used with first SSD that also act as primary disk while the other port has HDD of 1TB storage. But some might think why replace 1TB with some hundreds of SSD. I might soon partition this 2nd SSD for some space to fit in Linux distro.

Well, aside from making my laptop bit lighter, I wanna know if it's ergonomical, economical, performance upgrade (and any other Pros) of using SSD as a storage. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few advantages of an SSD in your scenario:

- Insensitive to shock, higher expected lifetime
- Considerably less energy consumption, so longer battery life. Less of a factor if you spin down the HDD for most of the time
- Less weight (around 100 grams)
- No humming
- Performance of laptop HDDs is especially low, so even for storage read/write performance can be a factor when moving data around

Comment: So from those advantages, it's still a good config to have SSD as a storage?

Comment: The only drawback is that you have to spend more money than on a HDD of same size, or in your case, having to spend money at all. If I would not have a HDD yet, I would go for the SSD straight away.

Comment: I actually already had a 1TB HDD as a storage. Cause I store lots of data (but this can be transferred to other disks). Right now, I'm thinking of swapping the 1Tb HDD to 1Tb or less of SSD.

Comment: That's what I am saying, if you had no other use for the HDD, more money would be wasted on the SSD. Crucial MX500 SSDs are in general a good deal, you can look them up in 1 TB, 512 GB sizes. SanDisk SSD Plus is also reliable and should be yet a bit cheaper.

Comment: what if, I'm replacing the wifi card port with the m.2 ? Assuming I'm either use wired internet or external wifi card.

Comment: Theoretically you can use that port. However you would need to check your laptop manual to see (a) which form factors fit there, (b) how the port is wired -- which devices are recognized at that port?). I would expect an NVME device to work there, but not a SATA device. It could also be both, or none.